# Initialization and existence endpoints for API

Tags: rest, api, http

### Requirements

- A way to check if a report exists
- A way to initialize a new report (client is unaware of the representation)
- A way to get the report

Note: A report either exists or does not and there is never more than one

### Idea 1

- `GET /account/{id}/report`

  - `404` if report doesn't exist
  - `200` if report does exist

But how to initialize? `POST`ing or `PUT`ting an empty body to the endpoint seems wrong (`POST` because we know where the resource is; `PUT` because we don't want nothing to be there), but maybe that's just me. An alternative would perhaps be to `GET /account/{id}/report/init`.

### Idea 2

- `GET /account/{id}/report`

  - `200` if report exists; return report
  - `200` if report doesn't exist; initialize and return report

But how to check if the report exists?

### Question

Both of my approaches fall short in different ways. What would be an appropriate approach to meeting the requirements while adhering to REST principles?

Comment: Why does the client need to know if the report existed or not? Does it matter to the client?

Comment: What is expected from "report" as a resource. Is it just an object or an action/operation/service? An object: Business layer might have created report/reports depending on the needs.In such a case Idea-1 seems the correct way. An action/operation/service:Then "200 if the report doesn't exist; initialize and return report" in Idea 2 seems the correct way. I am not sure about if mixing of the two case is right. Thnks

Answer (score 1):

> What would be an appropriate approach to meeting the requirements while adhering to REST principles?

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers.

There are two things that you should keep in mind.  First, that the reference application for the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the world wide web, which got along just fine with only GET and POST.  Second, that [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) is an important part of that story.

In HTTP, when the server returns a non-error status code in response to an unsafe request, that is an implicit instruction to the client (and any intermediary components) that previously cached representations should be invalidated.

Therefore, we usually want to arrange that *edits* are unsafe requests to the most important resource that will need to be refreshed if the change is successful.

So if I want to fetch a report, along with its meta-data?

```
GET /A3E7205B-6DC6-4685-9133-2759F739BC22
```

If I want the metadata without the report itself?

```
HEAD /A3E7205B-6DC6-4685-9133-2759F739BC22
```

If I want to change the report

```
POST /A3E7205B-6DC6-4685-9133-2759F739BC22
```

`PUT` and `PATCH` are valid alternatives to `POST` with more specific semantics, so are good to use there.

From the perspective of REST, *create* is just another kind of *edit*:

> A resource can map to the empty set, which allows references to be made to a concept before any realization of that concept exists -- Fielding

But part of the general flexibility of POST is that it supports the creation of a resource with a different identifier.  So you can do that if you prefer.

> if report doesn't exist; initialize and return report

GET semantics are supposed to be safe - caches are permitted to improve the experience by pre-loading resources, spiders are allowed to crawl them, and so on.  That doesn't mean that you can't create something -- HTTP constrains your semantics, not your implementation -- just that you need to be aware of the implications.

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and
> therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface
> or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that
> causes loss of property -- [Fielding 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

You observed:

> POSTing... an empty body to the endpoint seems wrong

No, it's fine, really.  You'll need to think through some of the other use cases (what does it mean to POST an empty body to a report that does exist?)

But in a case where creating a new report is effectively free, and the client doesn't need to know about the details?  Then just tell the client to `GET` the representation, and create what you need on demand.